# Maven tomcat:run goal and jsf annotation based component/converter/validator scanning

Tags: tomcat, configuration, maven, jsf-2

I'm developing a JSF 2.0 application (Mojarra+Primefaces) and using the maven build environment. Before I have used the faces-config.xml file for registering of my custom converters and validators, everything went well so far. Then I saw some syntactic sugar of JSF 2.0 - the annotation based configuration approach. And now I would like to use it, instead of the xml config file. A problem was that Mojarra didn't scan my annotated classes. I figured out that I needed to put the `<faces-config ... metadata-complete="false">` attribute to false. Now it works but only if I start my application with [`mvn tomcat:run-war`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) goal and not with the [`mvn tomcat:run`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) dynamic project, which is more comfortable for development. The specification of JSP 2.0 says that:

> If the  element in the WEB-INF/faces-config.xml file
>   contains metadata-complete attribute whose value is "true", the implementation must not perform annotation
>   scanning on any classes except for those classes provided by the implementation itself. Otherwise, continue as
>   follows.
>
> If the runtime discovers a conflict between an entry in the Application Configuration Resources and an annotation, the
>   entry in the Application Configuration Resources takes precedence.
>   All classes in WEB-INF/classes must be scanned.
>
> For every jar in the application's WEB-INF/lib directory, if the jar contains a "META-INF/faces-config.xml"
>   file or a file that matches the regular expression ".*.faces-config.xml" (even an empty one), all classes in
>   that jar must be scanned.

But it says nothing about dynamic projects running in maven build environment :)! Do anyone has a solution for that problem?

Cheers,

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, but found that adding the war:inplace goal made it work for me. i.e. use

```
mvn clean war:inplace tomcat:run
```

instead of just 'tomcat:run' and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `Log4jServletContainerInitializer` in `log4j-web` was somehow preventing the `FacesInitializer` in `javax.faces` from being called, which is responsible for processing annotated JSF classes.

Using `tomcat8-maven-plugin` and embedded tomcat 8.0.52.

`war:inplace` worked, or just removing `log4j-web` (with manual log4j initialization and context management).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES` fixed the `tomcat7:run` goal for me